# What does "Unknown error 517" mean in Android shell?

Tags: android, shell, mksh

I'm trying to write to a character device in Android shell. But mksh responds with "Unknown error 517" for a whole range of operations. I've tried to use *strace* to track down the issue, but its not helpful. This also occurs for a whole range of device nodes in AOS 4.4, but not in 4.2.

This is what I do:

```
# chmod 666 /dev/smd0
Unable to open /dev/smd0: Unknown error 517

# cat /dev/smd0
tmp-mksh: cat: /dev/smd0: Unknown error 517
```

The device is there and I can both create it (mknod) and remove it, so it's not a permission problem as far as I can see.

```
# ls /dev/smd0
crw-rw----    1 1000     1000      222,   0 Feb 13  2014 /dev/smd0
```

All I get in *strace* is:

```
ioctl(10</dev/tty>, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {c_iflags=0x500, c_oflags=0x5, c_cflags=0xbf, c_lflags=0x8a3b, c_line=0, c_cc="\x03\x1c\x7f\x15\x04\x00\x01\x00\x11\x13\x1a\x00\x12\x0f\x17\x16\x00\x00\x00"}) = 0
ioctl(10</dev/tty>, TIOCSPGRP, [23069]) = 0
[pid 23069] open("/dev/smd0", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 EPROBE_DEFER (Unknown error 517)
[pid 23069] open("/dev/smd0", O_WRONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 EPROBE_DEFER (Unknown error 517)
[pid 23069] write(2</dev/pts/5>, "Unable to open /dev/smd0: Unknown error 517\n", 44) = 44
```

Looking at the *mksh* sources in the [shf.c](https://github.com/MirBSD/mksh/blob/master/shf.c#L1134-L1138) file doesn't offer any insight either.

I also found the `EPROBE_DEFER` tag in the Linux Kernel sources, in the file: [../include/linux/errno.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/errno.h):

```
#define EPROBE_DEFER    517     /* Driver requests probe retry */
```

**Any ideas what could cause this problem?**

Comment: 6 years later, and 3k views, it seem... Are people still getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply because [bionic’s error definitions](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/private/bionic_errdefs.h) do not know about errno #517 (yet). `mksh` just uses what the operating system(’s C library) — in this case, Android’s bionic — provides.

[This part of `shf.c`](https://github.com/MirBSD/mksh/blob/mksh-R54/shf.c#L1137) generates the `Unknown error: %d` message when the underlying operating system(’s C library) doesn’t know about the error the underlying operating system(’s kernel) generates, which is here the case.

Comment: That is a confusing answer. You say that `mksh` is just using bionic, but yet, the bionic sources you pointed to, say nothing about the error that actually appears. So where are those strings coming from?

Answer (score 3):

As you've discovered, `517` is the value of the linux error `EPROBE_DEFER`, and it just means that a device driver is telling the linux kernel to try probing a particular device later. The Linux kernel calls a driver's `probe()` method when it wants the driver to prepare a device for usage.

Unfortunately, `EPROBE_DEFER` does not tell you why the probe needs to be retried, nor what you might need to do to ensure that it will succeed if you did retry. [Here is a thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.ports.arm.kernel/181232) complaining about that.

Comment: Yes, this seem a very lame error to have. This error seem to occur mostly when dealing with GPIO's and where a device driver is not reaching the GPIO (or USB) for some reason. In this case, on a Qualcomm based Samsung Device, */dev/smdN* should be mapped to a *shared memory driver* from [smd.c](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-msm-flo-3.4-kitkat-mr2/arch/arm/mach-msm/smd.c).

Comment: I want to add another thought on this issue. Further research seem to indicate that this device configuration are not using a *shared memory driver* for communicating with baseband. So perhaps the driver simply doesn't exist in the Kernel and thus failing in a similar manner as for GPIOs (as mentioned above). There are several major/minor devices in the tree, but only ttyHS/ttyHSL/ttyUSB are listed under */proc/tty/driver/* which seem to mean everything else is not accessible as an ordinary "tty".